# What is the difference between try/catch and MFC TRY/CATCH?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am refactoring some legacy C++ MFC code and have come across this construct:

```
TRY
{
    // do some stuff
}
CATCH
{
    // do some other stuff
}
END_CATCH
```

To me this seems quite unusual, and I am trying to understand what is the benefit of using `TRY/CATCH` in favor of `try/catch`.

I see that `TRY` creates an instance of `AFX_EXCEPTION_LINK` and I don't quite understand the purpose of this. My googling skill failed miserably.

Comment: c++ try/catch has DOS origin , and its support turned off by default say in `cl / link` while mfc handlers has a chance to work there.

Comment: @Але: [MS DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS) was introduced in 1981. [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) first appeared in 1985, with exceptions not being introduced until after 1990. What you are saying is incorrect. The primary programming languages for DOS were C and Pascal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MFC (and its [exception processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/exception-processing) macros) predate the C++98 language specification. The macros attempt to abstract common boilerplate code away, when using exceptions in MFC. The boilerplate code is necessary due to the design decision, that exceptions in MFC are dynamically allocated<sup>1</sup>, and need to be manually disposed.

The steps required to replace the MFC exception handling macros with C++ exception handling are documented under [Exceptions: Converting from MFC Exception Macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/exceptions-converting-from-mfc-exception-macros):

> To convert code using macros to use the C++ exception-handling keywords
>
> 1. Locate all occurrences of the MFC macros `TRY`, `CATCH`, `AND_CATCH`, `END_CATCH`, `THROW`, and `THROW_LAST`.
> 2. Replace or delete all occurrences of the following macros:
>
>    - `TRY` (Replace it with `try`)
>    - `CATCH` (Replace it with `catch`)
>    - `AND_CATCH` (Replace it with `catch`)
>    - `END_CATCH` (Delete it)
>    - `THROW` (Replace it with `throw`)
>    - `THROW_LAST` (Replace it with `throw`)
> 3. Modify the macro arguments so that they form valid exception declarations.
>
>    For example, change
>
>    ```
>    CATCH(CException, e)
>    ```
>
>    to
>
>    ```
>    catch(CException* e)
>    ```
> 4. Modify the code in the catch blocks so that it deletes exception objects as necessary. For more information, see the article [Exceptions: Catching and Deleting Exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/exceptions-catching-and-deleting-exceptions).
>
> Here is an example of exception-handling code using MFC exception macros. Note that because the code in the following example uses the macros, the exception `e` is deleted automatically:
>
> ```
> TRY
> {
>    // Do something to throw an exception.
>    AfxThrowUserException();
> }
> CATCH(CException, e)
> {
>    if (m_bPassExceptionsUp)
>       THROW_LAST();
>    if (m_bReturnFromThisFunction)
>       return;
>    // Not necessary to delete the exception e.
> }
> END_CATCH
> ```
>
> The code in the next example uses the C++ exception keywords, so the exception must be explicitly deleted:
>
> ```
> try
> {
>    // Do something to throw an exception.
>    AfxThrowUserException();
> }
> catch(CException* e)
> {
>    if (m_bPassExceptionsUp)
>       throw;
>    if (m_bThrowDifferentException)
>    {
>       e->Delete();
>       throw new CMyOtherException;
>    }
>    if (m_bReturnFromThisFunction)
>    {
>       e->Delete();
>       return;
>    }
>    e->Delete();
> }
> ```

The conversion is almost mechanical, as long as you remember to manually delete MFC exceptions by invoking [CException::Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cexception-class#delete).

---

<sup>1</sup> *This is in contrast to the C++ exception handling convention today: Throw by value, catch by (const) reference.*